# Consolidate large pack of huge .bib files

Tags: bibtex

I have a large number of `.bib` files, some of which include many `@String{a="B"} definitions, and there are many cross referencing 
dependencies.

In the days of [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) and [Google scholar](https://scholar.google.com), I find maintaining this not so worth the trouble. Is there a simple way to consolidate them
all into one large file, with all `@CrossRef{key,values}` entries 
fetched and `@String{..} definitions resolved and fully expanded.
I hear that [BibCard](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibcard?lang=en) can do the job. Is there a simple way for doing it,
preferably with a shell script rather than GUI, 
or should I experiment and study the manual?

Comment: I realise it may seem odd to suggest an MWE in this case, but not everybody uses `@string` and `crossref` etc. For me, it is easy to set up an example to experiment with because I use these myself. But, for others, it would be a considerable pain.

Comment: Sure, I will try to make an abbreviated example, to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a sane Unix-ish system and a `bash` shell ...

```bash
mkdir /tmp/bibs
cat <path to filename1>.bib <path to filename2>.bib ... <path to filenameN>.bib > /tmp/bibs/tmp.bib
pushd /tmp/bibs
biber --tool --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve -O big.bib tmp.bib 
rm tmp.bib
mv big.bib <directory where you want the combined bib>/
popd
rmdir /tmp/bibs
```

If you have separate files to define strings, you may need to list these first when concatenating the files. Note that this will resolve `xdata`, `crossref` etc. as well as strings.

For further information

```bash
biber --help
```

is the most useful source of information on the use of 'tool' mode which I found when looking into this a while ago.